# Carrierwave dynamic extension_white_list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models (`Document` & `DocumentType`). Using carrierwave I want to dynamically restrict the file extensions allowed on the Document based on it's DocumentType (which holds an array of acceptable file extensions). The problem is that `extension_white_list` seems to get called before the DocumentType gets associated with the Document. Ideas, Thoughts?

```
def create
  @document = Document.new document_params
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your uploader, you can do whatever you need, class, instance methods or fixed data.

```
def extension_white_list
  # Document.some_class_method
  # model.some_instance_method
  # fixed: %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
end
```

The issue could stem from the way Rails assigns params: you can't control the order.

In this case, split the lines to get the order you desire:

```
@document = Document.new document_params_without_file
@document.assign_attributes document_file_params
#or a mere @document.file_accessor = document_file_params
```

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. This saved my day. I wonder this was not accepted as answer and nobody has upvoted it yet. `the way Rails assign params` was the main reason. Thanks again.